# Ignore line breaks while parsing pdf with tabula

Tags: python, tabula, tabula-py

I am trying to read a pdf document using `tabula-py`. I however have an issue;` on one of the columns, there is a line that breaks the text into a new line and ignores the remaining the text. Here is an example of a column with line breaks

[image]

This produces this text when read:
`"VALUE ADD\rVAT ON NIP\r`

How do I make tabula ignore these line breaks? Here is my code:

```
tabula.read_pdf(file, pandas_options={"header":None}, pages='all', stream=True, lattice=True, multiple_tables=True, guess=False, password=password)
```

Thanks

Comment: @KJ The funny part is that `"ED TAX #############"` does not show up. Once it breaks, the remaining text on that same line is ignored. `TRANSFER FOR` is also ignored.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what else you want me to do here @KJ

Comment: I guess there is nothing that I can do here since the document is malformed. @KJ

Comment: I can't seem to find any solution to this. Thanks all the same @KJ

Comment: Added another screenshot of the pdf for more context if that helps @KJ

Comment: Have you tried with 'lattice=False'?

Comment: This does not work either @TalalSiddiqui